# rename image file using its Picasa name tags

Tags: picasa, exiftool

I am struggling with EXIFTOOL to rename a batch of JPG files using each file's Picasa name tags. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command in [exiftool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3) to find the **exact** name of the tag you want to copy from.

Once you find that, your command would be this, replacing TAG with the tag name you found from above.

```
exiftool "-Filename<${TAG}.%e" /path/to/files/
```

This command assumes that the value in the tag does not include the extension. If it does, then remove the `.%e`

Add [`-r`](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.  If this command is run under Linux/Mac/PowerShell, change the double quotes to single quotes.